# What are "nachas rights"?

Tags: words

I have just come across the phrase "nachas rights" and Google does not lead me to a definition.  It is in the writing of a British Jew, I expect from Stamford Hill.

Comment: Welcome Ian. Do you mean ph**r**ase? To elicit good quality answers consider adding as much information/context possible, e.g. where did you see this phase/phrase?

Comment: Sorry @Oliver, that's my bad spelling.  Given the current issues on the stackexchange network, I don't think it is wise to say where I saw it.

Comment: I don't know, but the first thing that comes to my mind is: "A man has the duty to make his children and his household rejoice on a festival." [Pesachim 109a]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Nachas" is a Yiddish word/concept that signifies pride in someone else's accomplishments, usually those of one's children. So by extension, "nachas rights" signifies the right of a parent to brag about such accomplishments.

Comment: Nachas is נחתֿ, so it's of Hebrew etymology